# Is there a way to make managed_file upload multiple files?

Tags: drupal-7

I am trying to upload multiple images at same time but the managed_file only enable the upload of one file , is there a way to make it upload mulitiple files or an other solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used on many projects this module: [Pluapload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload)
In most of the cases it's going to work out of the box. On the module page there is also a list of compatible modules